# Windows PATH variable doesn't work if path of the executable isn't on disc C

Tags: windows, path, cmd

I had some needs in setting up the Windows enviroment variable `PATH` in order to use some executables from console.

I wrote path to the executable in the `PATH` variable, but it doesn't work, thought it is because of the executable is not at the path "C:\Program Files", but on disk D, because before this day, I didn't have such a problem. How can I solve this?

P.S. If it can make some sense, I setting up NDK for Android development.

```
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Alias2014\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lucidlogix Technologies\VIRTU MVP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;D:\sdks\Android\ndk
```

Addition:

Moreover, when changing directory exactly to target folder and typing command, I get the same result! It is strange:

When I type it I get same error message. Moreover, when changing directory exactly to this folder and type command, I get the same result! it is strange.

```
D:\sdks\Android\ndk>dir
Том в устройстве D имеет метку Scrat's Projects
Серийный номер тома: 8297-302E

Содержимое папки D:\sdks\Android\ndk  

12.11.2014  04:26             9 820 ndk-build  
11.02.2014  04:20               292 ndk-build.cmd  
13.07.2014  12:11           198 144 ndk-depends.exe  
...
13.07.2014  12:11           880 640 ndk-stack.exe  
...
              14 файлов      1 154 110 байт  
              10 папок  726 615 486 464 байт свободно  

D:\sdks\Android\ndk>ndk_build  
"ndk_build" is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.

D:\sdks\Android\ndk>ndk_stack  
"ndk_stack" is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 

D:\sdks\Android\ndk>ndk_stack.exe  
"ndk_stack.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Dump:

```
ADSK_3DSMAX_x64_2012=C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2012\
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANS_OLD_ATTACH=1
APPDATA=C:\Users\SCRAT1995\AppData\Roaming
CM2012DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
CM2013DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
CM2015DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=SCRAT1995-ПК
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\SCRAT1995
ILBDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
ILLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
ILMDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05
KEYSHOT_EXTERNAL_LICENSE_FOLDER=C:\Program Files\DesignSpark\DesignSpark Mechanical 2.0\
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\SCRAT1995\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\SCRAT1995-ПК
NPTRACKINGTOOLS_INC=C:\Program Files\OptiTrack\Motive\inc
NPTRACKINGTOOLS_LIB=C:\Program Files\OptiTrack\Motive\lib
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Alias2014\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Lucidlogix Technologies\VIRTU MVP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;D:/sdks/Android/ndk
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 62 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3e04
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\SCRAT1~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\SCRAT1~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=SCRAT1995-ПК
USERNAME=SCRAT1995
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\SCRAT1995
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
VRAY_METASL_PATH_MSL12=C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\3dsmax 2012 for x64/metasl/msl12
VRAY_RT_FOR_3DSMAX2012_MAIN_x64=C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\RT for 3ds Max 2012 for x64/bin
VRAY_RT_FOR_3DSMAX2012_PLUGINS_x64=C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\RT for 3ds Max 2012 for x64/bin/plugins
VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
windows_tracing_flags=3
windows_tracing_logfile=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
```

Comment: Show us the value of the `path` variable

Comment: Well, you have to first make it quite clear what the problem is. Once that is clear, I'm sure we can help. We can only guess at what you are trying to do, and what you are actually doing. Please supply a clear and comprehensive description.

Comment: ....;D:\sdks\Android\ndk

Comment: Ok, in PATH variable, I added a path to the some sdk. The path are above, in the previous comment. But it still doesn't work, even after OS reloadind.

Comment: p.s. the path variable are in the "system variables"

Comment: Why so many minuses, what I've done wrong? I give additional information, think it's clear now...

Comment: It's not clear. You haven't told us what error message you are getting. You haven't told us what "doesn't work" about it. Does it not run the executable? What executable are you trying to run? Does it run the wrong version? What happens when you enter your executable name?

Comment: Ok, sorry, when I added path to the variable and reboot PC(it must be ok), when I try to call the executable or .bat file, then I just receive message " 'command' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Therefore cmd just don't see this path. im tryied to copy the executable to the some folder at the path "C:/Program files/..." and add it to the path variable and now it works. But problem is still here, because I want sdk to reside on other disks.

Comment: What happens if you type `D:\sdks\Android\ndk\command` ?  Have you used the `PATH` command to check what the actual PATH variable is, and double-checked it for typos?  Also, please copy and paste the PATH as shown in the command window into your question.

Comment: When I type it I get same error message. Moreover, when changing directory exactly to this folder and type command, I get the same result! it is strange.

Comment: You are typing `ndk_build` with an underscore, but the name of the script program file is `ndk-build.cmd` with a dash.  So it's not being found simply becuase you're using the wrong name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check PathExt variable.

Your path is too complex. It stops on first error.

Plus there's nothing stopping you typing full paths.

I have ONE extra path to my path statement that isn't standard.

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.LNK;.URL

[edit : moved answer from comments]

The program names contain a <kbd>-</kbd> but you are typing a <kbd>_</kbd>

Comment: PATHEXT is ok. Indeed, I can write absolute path, but it is doesn't work too!  Really. But another reason, because of which I need this path in variable, because this executable and scripts other programs use implicitly and they need this in variable too. It is really strange, because even if I open console in target folder, it still doesn't work

Comment: Dump your whole environment `set | clip` and paste here. Also rename one exe to an unknown extension (ie: zzzsss). Now try to execute this in CMD with full extension (and only CMD can execute files with unknown extensions). Also try typing the extensions on your existing files.

Comment: You also need to format code blocks./ Your path is wrong but probably from pasting. Put 4 x spaces in front of code lines.

Comment: Renaming didn't help me.

Comment: The program names contain a `-` but you aretyping a `_`.

Comment: Omg, this is it!  Thank you and sorry for wasting your time. I need more sleep -___-